# Text VFX border color

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

Hi does anyone know of a way to have an outline surrounding text in VFX edit? (Font border)

The reason for it is that such texts are better readable if placed over animations or movies with huge swings in brightness. And I kinda need that

I'll add scripting tag as well as maybe that's needed to get it

Comment: Well I found a way to solve it.
Its not perfect but for now I can live with it.
Add glow effect with blend mode exclusion

Comment: Do you mind converting your comment into an actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using glow to create an outline with this add-on: https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/b8e7fb9156b5c5d54fdab5d808dc7c1f
Change the blur width to change the outline width and change the multiply value to change opacity.
Offset the position of the outline to make a drop shadow.

[image]